# How to remove extra space below a TabBarView inside the body SliverToBoxAdapter in NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The space between tab bar view and bottom navigation bar is the extra space that I want to remove.

[image: The space between tab bar view and bottom navigation bar is the extra space that I want to remove]
in the image, you can see the space that shouldn't be there

```
class Tab_Bar2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Tab_Bar2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Tab_Bar2State createState() => _Tab_Bar2State();
}
class _Tab_Bar2State extends State<Tab_Bar2> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final bodyGlobalKey = GlobalKey();
  final List<Widget> myTabs = [
    Text(..),
    Text(..),
    Text(..),
    Text(..),
    Text(..),
Text(..),
  ];
  late TabController _tabController;
  late ScrollController _scrollController;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Dashboard"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFFC36A),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
            ),
          ]),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffFFC36A),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 60),
                child: Text(
                  'Drawer',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Log Out'),
              onTap: () {
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: NestedScrollView(

        controller: _scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, value) {
          return [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Column(
              children: [img1(), grid(), rsp(), LiveChart()],
            ),),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(

              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15,vertical: 15),
                    child: Text('Latest',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'railway',
                      color: Theme_Data.font_color,
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.5),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.5,vertical: 2.5),
                    height: 35,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(25),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 5),
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), // Creates border
                          color: Theme_Data.th_light_color),
                      tabs: myTabs,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                dividerColor: Colors.white
            ),
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
                SalesTable(),
                QuotationsTable(),
                PurchasesTable(),
                TransfersTable(),
                ConsumersTable(),
                SuppliersTable(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in above code i think there might be the issues  between the usage of SviverToBoxAdapter what widget should i use instead to achieve the required design